# UITableViewAutomaticDimension + AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I'm loading images from an API, and they have different heights and displaying in a `UITableView` which contains other type of cells (the reason I'm using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`)

I wanted to display (or reload) the cells containing the images using the image height, to avoid distortion.

I tried different solutions, but I'm having a hard time getting it to work?
Any tips or suggestions on how I can solve this?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I uploaded an example project here https://github.com/LucasCoelho/ImageLoading

The crash error is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'
```

I'm thinking it might be related to those conflicting NSAutolayoutConstraints

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85db176750 V:[UIImageView:0x7f85db17a090(72)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85db18ca90 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7f85db17a090]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85db179f70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85db18cb80 V:[UIImageView:0x7f85db17a090]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85db179f70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85db197e50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85db179f70(128)]>"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add height constraint to you imageView and create reference to it from you UITableViewCell subclass.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
      @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
      @IBOutlet weak var imageViewHeightConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

Then make use of **UIImageView+AFNetworking.h** method:

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
          placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                   success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                   failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

In success block you will need to set to downloaded image to your imageView and update **imageViewHeightConst** constant property.

```
imageView.image = image
imageViewHeightConst.constant = image.size.height
```

Also you need a way to inform your tableview that image has been downloaded and  tableview should be updated. So you can use delegate patter to solve this problem. In the implementation of delegate method you can update table view by using code below:

```
 tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

Eventually your cell subclass will look similar to this:

```
@objc protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func tableViewCell(cell: UITableViewCell, didLoadImage: UIImage)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewHeightConst: NSLayoutConstraint!

    weak var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
}

extension TableViewCell {

    func configureCellForURL(url: NSURL, placeholderImage: UIImage) {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        photoImageView.setImageWithURLRequest(request, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, success: { [weak self] (request, response, image) -> Void in

            self?.photoImageView?.image = image
            self?.imageViewHeightConst?.constant = image.size.height
            self?.delegate?.tableViewCell(self!, didLoadImage: image)

        }) { (request, response, error) -> Void in

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the crash. I uploaded a project with my problem. Do you mind taking a look at it? Thanks Roman

Comment: I have fixed your problem and created pull request. Check out your github example project.